# Kubernetes failed to pull image k8s.gcr.io

Tags: docker, kubernetes, proxy, kubeadm

I am trying to install Kubernetes on my CentOS machine, when I intialize the cluster, I have the following error.

I specify that I am behind a corporate proxy. I have already configured it for Docker in the directory: /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf
Docker work fine.

No matter how hard I look, I can't find a solution to this problem.

Thank you for your help.

```
# kubeadm init
W1006 14:29:38.432071    7560 version.go:102] could not fetch a Kubernetes version from the internet: unable to get URL "https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable-1.txt": Get "https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable-1.txt": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
W1006 14:29:38.432147    7560 version.go:103] falling back to the local client version: v1.19.2
W1006 14:29:38.432367    7560 configset.go:348] WARNING: kubeadm cannot validate component configs for API groups [kubelet.config.k8s.io kubeproxy.config.k8s.io]
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.19.2
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
        [WARNING Firewalld]: firewalld is active, please ensure ports [6443 10250] are open or your cluster may not function correctly
        [WARNING HTTPProxy]: Connection to "https://192.168.XXX.XXX" uses proxy "http://proxyxxxxx.xxxx.xxx:xxxx/". If that is not intended, adjust your proxy settings
        [WARNING HTTPProxyCIDR]: connection to "10.96.0.0/12" uses proxy "http://proxyxxxxx.xxxx.xxx:xxxx/". This may lead to malfunctional cluster setup. Make sure that Pod and Services IP ranges specified correctly as exceptions in proxy configuration
        [WARNING IsDockerSystemdCheck]: detected "cgroupfs" as the Docker cgroup driver. The recommended driver is "systemd". Please follow the guide at https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/cri/
[preflight] Pulling images required for setting up a Kubernetes cluster
[preflight] This might take a minute or two, depending on the speed of your internet connection
[preflight] You can also perform this action in beforehand using 'kubeadm config images pull'
error execution phase preflight: [preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
        [ERROR ImagePull]: failed to pull image k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver:v1.19.2: output: Error response from daemon: Get https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/: remote error: tls: handshake failure
, error: exit status 1
        [ERROR ImagePull]: failed to pull image k8s.gcr.io/kube-controller-manager:v1.19.2: output: Error response from daemon: Get https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/: remote error: tls: handshake failure
, error: exit status 1
        [ERROR ImagePull]: failed to pull image k8s.gcr.io/kube-scheduler:v1.19.2: output: Error response from daemon: Get https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/: remote error: tls: handshake failure
, error: exit status 1
        [ERROR ImagePull]: failed to pull image k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy:v1.19.2: output: Error response from daemon: Get https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/: remote error: tls: handshake failure
, error: exit status 1
        [ERROR ImagePull]: failed to pull image k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.2: output: Error response from daemon: Get https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/: remote error: tls: handshake failure
, error: exit status 1
        [ERROR ImagePull]: failed to pull image k8s.gcr.io/etcd:3.4.13-0: output: Error response from daemon: Get https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/: remote error: tls: handshake failure
, error: exit status 1
        [ERROR ImagePull]: failed to pull image k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.7.0: output: Error response from daemon: Get https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/: remote error: tls: handshake failure
, error: exit status 1
```

```
# kubeadm config images pull
W1006 17:33:41.362395   80605 version.go:102] could not fetch a Kubernetes version from the internet: unable to get URL "https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable-1.txt": Get "https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable-1.txt": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
W1006 17:33:41.362454   80605 version.go:103] falling back to the local client version: v1.19.2
W1006 17:33:41.362685   80605 configset.go:348] WARNING: kubeadm cannot validate component configs for API groups [kubelet.config.k8s.io kubeproxy.config.k8s.io]
failed to pull image "k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver:v1.19.2": output: Error response from daemon: Get https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/: remote error: tls: handshake failure
, error: exit status 1
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
```

Comment: any update on this ? feel free to update the status of question if any of below answer resolves you issues or do share your solution if manage to resolve.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue on version `version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"25", GitVersion:"v1.25.2"`  when i tried joining a second control panel.

```
error execution phase preflight: [preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
    [ERROR ImagePull]: failed to pull image k8s.gcr.io/coredns:v1.9.3: output: E0923 04:47:51.763983    1598 remote_image.go:242] "PullImage from image service failed" err="rpc error: code = NotFound desc = failed to pull and unpack image \"k8s.gcr.io/coredns:v1.9.3\": failed to resolve reference \"k8s.gcr.io/coredns:v1.9.3\": k8s.gcr.io/coredns:v1.9.3: not found" image="k8s.gcr.io/coredns:v1.9.3"
time="2022-09-23T04:47:51Z"...
```

> See #99321 it's now k8s.gcr.io/coredns/coredns:v1.9.3 instead of
> k8s.gcr.io/coredns:v1.9.3 and i don't now why
>
> by kluevandrew,
> refererence: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/112131

This worked, am using containerd:

```
crictl pull k8s.gcr.io/coredns/coredns:v1.9.3
ctr --namespace=k8s.io image tag k8s.gcr.io/coredns/coredns:v1.9.3 k8s.gcr.io/coredns:v1.9.3
```

docker solution:

```
docker pull k8s.gcr.io/coredns/coredns:v1.9.3
docker tag k8s.gcr.io/coredns/coredns:v1.9.3 k8s.gcr.io/coredns:v1.9.3
```

Comment: Thank you! The docker solution worked. But what the heck, `coredns` isn't even a thing I specify for my app, how are we supposed to fix that? Isn't it hardcoded into Docker Desktop or something?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe root certificates on your machine are outdated - so it does not consider certificate of k8s.gcr.io as valid one. This message `x509: certificate signed by unknown authority` hints to it.

Try to update them: `yum update ca-certificates || yum reinstall ca-certificates`

Comment: Maybe also `update-ca-trust extract`? I found similar issue described [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/43924#issuecomment-317355060)

Comment: Same result. I'm looking for another method to have these images

Answer (score 2):

I just did a dig to k8s.gcr.io, and I added the IP given by the request to /etc/hosts.

```
# dig k8s.gcr.io

; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-26.P2.el7_9.2 <<>> k8s.gcr.io
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 44303
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;k8s.gcr.io.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
k8s.gcr.io.     21599   IN  CNAME   googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com.
googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com. 299 IN A    64.233.168.82

;; Query time: 72 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Tue Nov 24 11:45:37 CST 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 103

# cat /etc/hosts
64.233.168.82   k8s.gcr.io
```

And now it works!

```
# kubeadm config images pull
W1124 11:46:41.297352   50730 configset.go:348] WARNING: kubeadm cannot validate component configs for API groups [kubelet.config.k8s.io kubeproxy.config.k8s.io]
[config/images] Pulled k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver:v1.19.4
[config/images] Pulled k8s.gcr.io/kube-controller-manager:v1.19.4
[config/images] Pulled k8s.gcr.io/kube-scheduler:v1.19.4
[config/images] Pulled k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy:v1.19.4
[config/images] Pulled k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.2
[config/images] Pulled k8s.gcr.io/etcd:3.4.13-0
[config/images] Pulled k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.7.0
```

Comment: This helped fix the issue temporarily but why wouldn't the dns resolution work? Everything is configured correctly in resolv.conf

Answer (score 0):

Working also with `v1.19.2` - I've got the same error.

It seems to be related to the issue mentioned [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/95487) (and I think also in [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/95406)).

I re-install kubeadm on the node and ran the `kubeadm init` workflow again - it is now working with `v1.19.3` and the errors are gone.

All master nodes images are pulled successfully.

Also verified with:

```
sudo kubeadm config images pull
```

(*) You can run `kubeadm init` with `--kubernetes-version=X.Y.Z` (`1.19.3` in our case).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. Maybe as others say, it's because of an outdated certificate. I believe it's not required to delete anything.

Simple solution was running one of those two commands, which will reconnect to Container repositories via:

`podman login`

`docker login`

[Source: podman-login](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-login.1.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check **imageRepository** in **kubeadm-config** configmap (or your kubeadm config file, if You run something like **kubeadm init --config=/tmp/kubeadm-config.yml**).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is described here - https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/114978

They've moved the coredns image to another registry. Since I'm initializing the cluster using a kubeadm yaml file I had to add a line under the `dns` field as the last answer suggests, see here:

```
dns:
  imageRepository: k8s.gcr.io/coredns
```

This basically does what some people suggested above via manual commands.

Answer (score 0):

Official image repository for Kuberentes is got changed.

Old one :  `k8s.gcr.io`

New one : `registry.k8s.io`

[image]

**20th** of **March** images started getting migrated although in April first or second week those will be in **ReadOnly** mode.